# Invalid get index 'x' candy crush game on Godot

Tags: godot, index-error

I am having a problem with  i think is the index. i can't run the code, somehow the "while" is wrong and i don't know how. I am coping with a youtube video how to build it. but i think the video is outdated, is from 3 years ago. if somone get a ideia how to run it i would be grateful. (sorry bad English, not my formal language)

some phrases will be in portuguese but i think is not gonna damege it...

edit: i think is not a error. but its a red phrase is on the scrubber area

```
extends Node2D

# Grid Variaveis
export (int) var width;
export (int) var height;
export (int) var x_start;
export (int) var y_start;
export (int) var offset;

var possible_pieces = [
preload("res://cenario/abacate.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/sprite2.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/Node2D.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/sprite 3.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/tomato.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/uva.tscn")   
];

var all_pieces =[];

func _ready():
    randomize();
    all_pieces  = make_2d_array();
    spawn_pieces();
    
func make_2d_array():
    var array = [];
    for i in width:
           array.append([]);
           for j in height:
               array[i].append(null)
    return array;
    
func spawn_pieces():
    for i in width:
        for j in height:
            #choose a random number and store it
            var rand = floor(rand_range(0, possible_pieces.size()));
            var piece = possible_pieces[rand].instance();
            var loops = 0
            while(match_at(i, j, piece[rand].color) && loops < 100):
                rand = floor(rand_range(0, possible_pieces.size()));
                loops += 1;
                piece = possible_pieces[rand].instance();
            #instance that piece from the array
            
            add_child(piece);
            piece.position = grid_to_pixel(i, j);
            all_pieces[i][j] = piece;
            
func match_at(i, j, color):
    
    if i > 1:
        if all_pieces[i - 1][j] != null && all_pieces[i - 2][j] != null:
            if all_pieces[i - 1][j].color == color && all_pieces[i - 2][j].color == color:
                return true;
    if j > 1:
        if all_pieces[i][j - 1] != null && all_pieces[i][j - 2] != null:
            if all_pieces[i][j - 1].color == color && all_pieces[i][j - 2].color == color:
                return true;    
                
    pass;
    
func grid_to_pixel(column, row):
    var new_x = x_start + offset * column;
    var new_y = y_start + -offset * row;
    return Vector2(new_x, new_y);
```

Comment: So what is your `match_at` supposed to return when none of the conditions evaluate to `true`? `pass;` most certainly is not the correct thing to do

Comment: You should also include the exact error message you get, *"i can't run the code"* is a very unhelpful problem description

Comment: sorry.. the error is (invalid get index 'x' (on base 'node2D (script.gd)').

Comment: and i think the much error is on 'spawn_pieces' line 41 (the while) and '_ready' line  24

Comment: If i understand. The error is one this line `while(match_at(i, j, piece[rand].color) && loops < 100):`

Answer (score 1):

You have `possible_pieces` with a bunch of `PackedScene`s:

```
var possible_pieces = [
preload("res://cenario/abacate.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/sprite2.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/Node2D.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/sprite 3.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/tomato.tscn"),
preload("res://cenario/uva.tscn")   
];
```

Then you pick one and instantiate it:

```
var rand = floor(rand_range(0, possible_pieces.size()));
var piece = possible_pieces[rand].instance();
```

Thus `piece` is a `Node`. So when you do this: `piece[rand]` you are trying to use index access on a `Node` and that does not work. That is the problem with this line:

```
while(match_at(i, j, piece[rand].color) && loops < 100):
```

I believe you want to do this instead:

```
while(match_at(i, j, piece.color) && loops < 100):
```

---

*For future reference, specifying the types of your variables might help you avoid this kind of errors. See [Static typing in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html). By the way, even though the term "Type Hints" stuck, they are not hints, they are actual type declarations.*

Comment: i think that worked. no more errors. i just not understat the part of `var rand = floor(rand_range(0, possible_pieces.size()));
var piece = possible_pieces[rand].instance();´ do i just put the code under the 'panckedScenes`?

Comment: @RodLod You already have that code. I took those lines from your question. The context is that you have `possible_pieces` which is an `Array` that has `PackedScene`s. Then, sometimes later, those lines are going to execute. And because `possible_pieces` is an `Array` with `PackedScene`s, `rand` will be a valid index for that `Array`, and thus `possible_pieces[rand]` will be a `PackedScene` and thus `possible_pieces[rand].instance()` will be `Node`. So `piece` will be a `Node`. Now that we know that, then we know that `piece[rand]` does not work. It is a line of deduction.

Answer (score 0):

The function `match_at`returns null if it doesn't match any of the conditions.
Replace the `pass;` for `return false;` or create an `else` statement to do something if needed, and then the `return false;`.

As mentioned below by @Theraot i realized the `pass;` its not the problem

Comment: I put the pass to see if chage anything.  I tried to chage it with return_false; bjt nothing chage again. Just not tried the else. When i have the time i will test it

Comment: by the way does the error happen in the first loop of for or it happened later?

Comment: Here `match_at` is not typed, so it returns a variant. And if does not reach a `return` statement, that is `null`. And `null` is falsy, if you know what I mean. Hence changing it to `return false` has the same result (given how it is being used). So, you are correct to identify that is not great, but it is not the cause of the problem.